# Modified/remove entries not working on Xbox? XNA

Tags: c#, xml, xna

Ever since I ported my game to Xbox with XNA the code that's supposed to modify and remove entries on the as such as chests, NPC ect hasn't been working. It worked while I was testing on the PC but now it isn't. I double checked over a previous build and it's all the same so I can't reason out what's wrong, I've also debugged the hell out of it but everything returns as it should be.

Here is the code that modifies/removes content: http://pastebin.com/9QKEhAM3

I think if anything that's where the hiccup will be at I just can't find it. I definitely think it's something to do with the one of the quirks of PC/XBOX differences because when I create another windows version of my game Chests and NPC disappear as they should.

If you could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: So when debugging on the 360, if you put a breakpoint on the line if (mapEntry == null) in the RemoveChest method, does it ever get hit? That will help know if the method is even being called or if the problem is happening somewhere else.

Comment: @GeorgeClingerman Yes it does get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it! It's a really ugly fix but a fix never the less. What I did was simply removed the if removedEntries > 0 conditional. Works like a charm! I'd really like to thank @Blau for all your help as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some try... catch statements...

I'm sure you have a problem with an uncontrolled exception.

You can use this extended game class too, I've used it in my games and is very effective.

http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2009/07/a-more-robust-exception-system/

Comment: I'm sorry this is a little beyond my abilities. I've created the ExceptionGame class and added the method to my session class where I remove/modify content but I don't know how I'm supposed to use it. Please bear with me I'm still a rookie.

Comment: if you inherits your game from ExceptionGame class in the xbox 360, without debugging, if an exception is throwed, the game will inform you about that exception before closing. I have seen implementations that lets you send a private message to the developer.

Comment: Okay I did it and it doesn't inform me about any exceptions.

Comment: are you sure that you don't have any try... catch.. statement that is capturing exceptions and is not handling them right? Not, in this code, but in TileManager class or other place

Comment: I don't think so. I've been debugging it and I think something is going wrong in my ModifyMap method in Map.cs. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/ZRx9t950

Comment: Why have to check with anidated delegates?, that is hard to debug. And why don't remove the entries in a straight way?, I suppose MapEntry<Chest> is a class, it should be easier... foreach (MapEntry<Chest> entry in RemovedMapChest) map.ChestEntries.Remove(entry);

Comment: It removes the chest, it just doesn't stay removed when I reload the map.

Comment: I've been doing some more debugging and line 38 of the first set of code I posted(Content Removal/Modification) doesn't get hit. Which would mean that removedentries probably always equals 0. That would mean the removeall method in my missingmethod class probably isn't doing it's job right. Here is the method: http://pastebin.com/d2GtUrCL

Comment: I tried that method and the chest still doesn't disappear. I also checked if line 38 was now being hit and it still wasn't so I think it could mean there is nothing in the removedMapChests list.

Comment: For some reason removedEntries using delegates returns as -2. Using foreach returns as 0.